# Getting the last called system call

Tags: c++, windows, system-calls

Does anybody know if there's a way to obtain the last system call made by a specific thread
(in C++/Windows)?
thanks:)

Comment: System call? In Windows?

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you mean by a "system call"?

Comment: something like "wait", "read", "open" and such. I'm looking at the code of "Process Hacker" and they get the last system call using "NtQueryInformationThread". The problem with it is 1. Microsoft does not recommend using it : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: and 2. I could not find information about how to use it in order to get the last call or anything else besides Pending IO status...

Comment: @Idov: Does it surprise you to learn that a program with "Hacker" in its name uses a function that Microsoft discourages you from using? There's no *standard* use case for this type of functionality. Over 99.9% of apps just don't need this information, so there's no handy built-in mechanism to access it. You're either writing a program similar to Process Hacker, and you'll just have to accept that it may not work when the internals of the OS are changed, or there's a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: what? how would DLL injection help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can define the set of system calls (which I assume will all map nicely to Win32 APIs exported by kernel32.dll - e.g. CreateFile, WriteFile, WaitForSingleObject, etc...), you can use the Detours library to trap DLL calls and use that to monitor the "last" call made.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/